# Remove files from an array of files and directories using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file, directory

I'm trying to get a list of directories in a path by using `scandir` and removing the files from the array but I'm getting errors from my echo.

I'm using the code

```
$path = "Calltypes/";
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($files); $i++) {
    if(!is_dir($files[$i]))
        array_splice($files, $i, 1);
}

echo sizeof($files);
```

This is the echo output:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 32
2
```

The Calltypes/ path has 3 folders and 1 txt file.

**Edit: line 32 is**

```
if(!is_dir($files[$i]))
```

Comment: I would use @RomanPerekhrest's solution, but your actual problem is caused by the fact that the element with index 0 does not exist any more after your `array_diff()` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `foreach` instead of `for`. After that use `unset` because `array_splice` will rearrange keys so you will get errors

```
$path = "Calltypes/";
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_dir($path.$files[$key]))
       unset($files[$key]);
}
echo sizeof($files);
```

Comment: This works but I had to use 
    if(!is_dir($path.$files[$key]))

Answer (score 4):

In your case, `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` occurs because `arry_diff` returns an array containing all the entries from the 1st array ***without reindexing***. That means, that `$files` array would not have `0` index after `array_diff` processing.

Instead of "splicing" array items while iterating in the loop - use `array_filter` to get only directory names:

```
$path = "Calltypes/";
$files = scandir($path);
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

$files = array_filter($files, "is_dir");
```

Comment: Using this my sizeof echo is "0". This can't be right because I have 3 folders and 1 txt file so the sizeof after the filter should be 3?

Comment: @AdamStück You should `var_dump($files);` after each step to see what is happening.

Comment: @AdamStück, that should not happen. You are doing something wrong. You got some other issues that don't relate to my approach

Comment: I used your snippet and only added an ``echo sizeof($files);`` at the end so there is no code being used you don't know about.

Comment: @AdamStück, wrong, my code works ... except your current conditions/tricks